# Android Cloud app building blocks

Tags: android, cloud

I am a beginner in Android app making. I want to build a basic Cloud app which can take back up of the user's data and can store it on remote server. I know there are millions of such app, but would like to know some link that I can refer to begin my App building.

I hope I am clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). You can do all of the coding in eclipse, and once you have it set up properly it's fairly painless to deploy your webapp to the server and start testing your android app.

If you require a true relational database, google app engine makes you pay extra. If you don't however, there is no charge for the standard datastore. Also, app engine is free until you have lots of traffic to/from the server.

You can develop in Java or python. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) is the setup guide for eclipse (Java).

Comment: HI @cmpdlee thanks or the reply, I wanted to know where can start from for my android mobile app, as in to refer the coding struture or such kind of apps

Comment: Ok do you want to back up all the data from all installed apps on the phone? Or just from your own app?

Comment: From all the apps, say messages Contacts Images, as it is done in icloud